# Dumbed down patch command

Tags: patch

I would like to issue a patch command which is somewhat dumber than the default, but I cannot find the right flags (if they exist at all).

I don't want it to create `.rej` or `.orig` files, not even when the patch fails. If the patch fails I'd like the original files to remain unchanged.

I don't want it to try guessing if the patch is reversed or not, or try matching the lines before or after those given in the patch. If the lines at the given line numbers do not match, it should fail.

I've tried with `-f -N -V never -r - --no-backup-if-mismatch`, but still backup files are created and "fuzzy" matching is tried.

Comment: If this (as it appears) is about the Linux 'patch' command, I suspect it'd be better suited to [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)...

Comment: @DanPuzey Yes, it's about the Linux `patch` command. I wasn't aware of the Super User site. Should I re-post this question there and "close" this one?

Comment: if you hang tight, the question will likely be flagged by the community here and migrated automatically - no need to repost :-)

Comment: I'd say `patch` qualifies as "software tools commonly used by programmers" as described in the [help/on-topic], so it's a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it with `--dry-run -s` and only apply if it doesn't report any problems (you may be able to key off the return code).

For disabling the fuzz, you need `-F0`

Comment: Disabling the fuzz works, I should have tried `-F0` before asking... As for the dry run, I was hoping it could be done without running `patch` twice (if there are no errors).

Comment: Not really possible. As patch works on chunks rather than files / sections, if you could do what you describe then you'd potentially end up with partially patched files and no warning of it. This way at least the patch is atomic.